# How to compensate ray displacement caused by refraction in glass slab

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, refraction

I need a nudge in the right direction, i guess (this is not a homework question).

I want to calculate the total length of a ray from an emitter to a target which passes through a slab with known properties.

Given:

- Position of Emitter and Target $P_\text{Source}, P_\text{Dest}$
- Refractive indices of the slab and surrounding medium $n_1, n_2$
- position and thickness of the slab $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$

[image: Double refraction on glass slab]

Question:

1. What angle of incidence $\theta_i$ is required for a ray cast from $P_{source}$ to intersect $P_\text{dest}$?
2. How long is the path the ray actually takes?

I know the incident ray is displaced parallely depending on angle of incidence and refractive indices. I have also found some equation for the determiantion of the offset, but i am still not sure how to apply it to my problem:
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\Delta y = d_2 \tan \theta_i \left( 1- \frac{\cos \theta_i}{\sqrt{n^2 - \sin^2 \theta_r}}\right)
\end{equation}
$$

where $\Delta_y$ is the offset of the ray emerging from the slab.

Could you give me a few directions?

Comment: Looks like an ideal use for [Fermat's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_principle).

Comment: Hint: if you know $\Delta_y$ and you know the thickness of the slab, you can figure out the (x,y,z) location of the exiting ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using the vertical displacement:

$$\begin{equation}\tag{2}
h_d = d_1 tan(\theta) + \frac{d_2  tan(\theta)}{n} + d_3  tan(\theta)
\end{equation}$$

solved for $\theta$ this becomes

$$\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\theta = \arctan \left( \frac{h_d}{d_1 + d_3 + \frac{d_2}{n}} \right)
\end{equation}$$